# Window animation closes suddenly [Titanium]

Tags: ios, animation, window, titanium

I have an app where the user clicks a button to open the menu. On pressing the button, the window slides towards the right to open. To close the window, the user swipes it to the left to close it.

After closing, if the user presses the button within a span of 2 seconds the window opens and closes. Why is this happening ?? Does this have to do something with the duration ?

Code:

```
   var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({left:0, width:200});

   var slideLeft = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
   slideLeft.left = 0; 
   slideLeft.duration = 200;

   var slide_it_right = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
   slideRight.left = -320; 
   slideRight.duration = 300;

  button.addEventListener('click',function(){
              win.open(slideLeft);
  });
  win.addEventListener('swipe',function(){
          win.close(slideRight);
  });
```

Comment: i dont think you should close the win

Answer (score 0):

Just make a window of menuView plus normalView width and then slide the view by setting left.